# Is it possible to scale (increase Cores) a running GCP CloudSQL in HA configuration with zero-downtime?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is it possible to increase Cores of a running GCP CloudSQL in HA configuration with zero-downtime?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance. I enabled the HA at the creation time. Latter, I modified it increasing the number of cores and I got the following message [image]

So I really think that you will have a downtime even with HA since this one is triggered when the instance become unhealthy as is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability#failover-process)